# CodeEffects Rule Engine - Template for ReactJS - how to add alphanumeric validation to built-in text field input?

Tags: reactjs, validation, rule-engine, business-rules, codeeffects

I want to add input format validation(allow only alphanumerics) to text input present in the official CodeEffects Rule Engine template for React. Does this template supports this customization. If yes, then how?
I have attached screenshot of the associated Rule Engine React Frontend page containing that input field.

I hv used this template by downloading it from below URL:
https://codeeffects.com/Doc/Business-Rule-Demo-Project/

[Click here for checking attached screenshot of Rule Engine page from CodeEffects React template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAJgo.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

All inputs in the editor are type-based. If a field in your source object is declared as a numeric type (int, long, decimal, double, etc) its input textbox will accept only numeric values in the editor. This is the default platform-independent behavior. To test, go to https://codeeffects.com/Business-Rules-Engine-Demo, select the "New evaluation type rule..." option from the Rules menu, create a rule like "Check if Pulse is equal to" and try to input anything into the Pusle input. You'll notice that it accepts only numeric chars.